# General Query About How To Detect What Intent Called The Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-pendingintent

So I have a app with different settings for up to 8 things and I have been trying to pass on which PendingIntent or Intent triggered my service but all to no avail. I have tried using the .getExtra() and .putExtra() and also trying to figure out what the int flags and startId do, but nothing worked. Could someone please tell me a way I can figure out which intent/pendingintent called on my service? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onStartCommand()` you get passed an `Intent`. That should contain your "extras".

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call *getIntent()* in your activity to get this info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()

Comment: Okay, so the value returned by getIntent() will be what kind of data type? Integer or string or what?

Comment: *getIntent()* will return an Intent object.  The extras can be grabbed by calling *getIntent().getExtras()* - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()

This will give you a bundle that should contain your values (Obtained from methods like *getInt()*) - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Comment: Yea, I cannot use getIntent() inside a class that extends service :(

Comment: Is there a way I can use a method to get the identity of an intent?

Comment: In your service, are you connecting to it via the `bindService(...)` method?  If so, one of those parameters is the calling Intent as well.

Comment: No, I'm not calling it.